# Why does not result of GetName method in the FontFamily instance differ depending on CultureInfo.LCID in the argument?

Tags: c#, .net

I've encountered strange behavior of the GetName method in the FontFamily class in the .NET. It returns same value no matter what Culture id I give to it!
For example, this fragment:

```
foreach (var cultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
   Console.WriteLine(FontFamily.Families[0].GetName(cultureInfo.LCID));
}
```

displays this output all the way down:

```
Agency FB
Agency FB
Agency FB
...
```

What's the point in creating such a method?

Comment: TrueType fonts have a 'name' table that can describe the font names in different languages.  That you don't have a font on your machine that takes advantage of that capability is not unusual, you'd find such a font on a machine halfway around the world.

Comment: And what if it's the same story for every member of FontFamily.Families? -) My computer doesn't have any of these fonts installed?

Comment: It seems that it is a feature for Eastern languages. Only their LCID make a difference for some of the FontFamily.Families members. All Western LCID's give identical font names.